# Show that if we have a matrix $A$, which can be written as $A=DD^T$ for some matrix $D$, then...

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, transpose

we have $\bar{x}^TA\bar{x}\geq 0$ for any column vector $\bar{x}$.

I do not really know where to start, but I do know that I can somehow show the scalar $\bar{x}^TA\bar{x}$ is equal to $||D^T\bar{x}||^2$ and that would be enough. Unfortunately, I  cannot see how.

Comment: To start, note that for any two vectors, $x,y$, we have $x^T y = x\cdot y$, the dot product. Now use the fact that $A = DD^T$, we have $x^TAx = x^T DD^T x$, can you see this as the dot product of two vectors? (Note, $(pq)^T = q^T p^T$.)

Comment: $\bar{x}^TA\bar{x}=\bar{x}^TDD^{T}\bar{x} =(\bar{x}^TD) (\bar{x}^TD)^{T}=\|\bar{x}^TD\|^{2}\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $A = D D^T$, it's easy to see that $A$ must be square matrix so $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Let $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

\begin{align}
x^T A x &= x^T D D^T x\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} (D^T x)^T (D^T x)\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=} ||D^T x||^2\\
&\geq 0
\end{align}

Equality $(1)$ follows by the standard result $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ and $(B^T)^T = B$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$.

Equality $(2)$ follows because $D^T x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. $D^T x$ is a column vector. For any column vector $v$, we have $||v||^2 = v^T v$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
||D^T\bar{x}||^2 &=\langle D^T\bar{x} , D^T\bar{x}\rangle\\
&= (D^T\bar{x})^TD^T\bar{x}\\
&=\bar{x}^TDD^T\bar{x}\\
&=\bar{x}^TA\bar{x}
\end{align*}